# SQL multiple case statement

Tags: sql

How can I make this correct? I am getting an error saying: 
***Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'.***

```
SELECT *
FROM Companies
Order By 
    CASE @OrderByField
        WHEN 'CompanyName' THEN CompanyName
        WHEN 'CreatedDate' THEN CreatedDate
    END, 
    CASE @Direction
        WHEN 'DESC' THEN DESC
        WHEN 'ASC' THEN ASC
    END
```

Can I not have two case statements? If not, how can i pass in the name of the order by field and direction as parameters?

Thanks!

Another problem surface after the first one is solved...

If I include a field that doesn't have the datatype of string, if throws an error. 
For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Companies
Order By
  CASE @Direction WHEN 'DESC' THEN
    CASE @OrderByField
        WHEN 'CompanyName' THEN CompanyName
        WHEN 'CreatedDate' THEN CreatedDate
        WHEN 'Score' THEN Score

    END
  END DESC,
  CASE @Direction WHEN 'ASC' THEN
    CASE @OrderByField
        WHEN 'CompanyName' THEN CompanyName
        WHEN 'CreatedDate' THEN CreatedDate
        WHEN 'Score' THEN Score
    END
  END ASC
```

@OrderByField is type of nvarchar(50)
assume Score has a datatype of float.

Above throws an error like the one below even if i am not trying to order by the score field. **Error converting data type nvarchar to float.**

Similarly, including a createddate throws an error: **Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

Will be very appreciated if anyone can help out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758655/ms-sql-conditional-order-by-asc-desc-question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884884/conditional-sql-order-by-asc-desc-for-alpha-columns

Comment: i will be appreciated if you can find a post on this as well!

Comment: See answer by LarsW on the first link, or `case` part of answer by gbn on second link; those seem to be exactly what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `ASC` and `DESC` are keywords, you can't have them as return value from a `CASE`.

You can make two cases, one for `ASC` and one for `DESC`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Companies
Order By 
  CASE
    WHEN @OrderByField = 'CompanyName' AND @Direction = 'ASC' THEN CompanyName
    WHEN @OrderByField = 'CreatedDate' AND @Direction = 'ASC' THEN CreatedDate
  END ASC,
  CASE
    WHEN @OrderByField = 'CompanyName' AND @Direction = 'DESC' THEN CompanyName
    WHEN @OrderByField = 'CreatedDate' AND @Direction = 'DESC' THEN CreatedDate
  END DESC
```

Note that all values from a case has to have the same data type, so you might need one pair of cases for string and one pair for dates.

Comment: My apology for not seeing your comment below. thanks for forecasting the problem that i would run into.

Comment: Question: Will your sql statement not result in something like this:   "SELECT * FROM Companies Order By CompanyName ASC, DESC" ?  since the second desc is outside of the case statement and will get ran no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a keyword from a case statement.

But you can achieve what you want by ordering in two ways, but return a constant expression for the order you don't want:

```
SELECT *
FROM Companies
Order By
  CASE @Direction WHEN 'DESC' THEN
    CASE @OrderByField
        WHEN 'CompanyName' THEN CompanyName
        WHEN 'CreatedDate' THEN CreatedDate
    END
  END DESC,
  CASE @Direction WHEN 'ASC' THEN
    CASE @OrderByField
        WHEN 'CompanyName' THEN CompanyName
        WHEN 'CreatedDate' THEN CreatedDate
    END
  END ASC
```

Non-matching cases will return `null` and so will be ignored for ordering purposes.

Comment: Very elegant! this is exactly what i want. Two nested case statements was my approach after posting my question. You got there first!

Comment: Will be appreciated if you can help out the above problem. Thanks Bohemian!

Comment: You need to cast `CreatedDate` to a character type, but the syntax varies across databases: What database are you using?

Comment: i am using sql server 2013